# Need help decoding registry binary data

Tags: python, windows, registry, winreg

I am trying to build a small app using shellbags in the windows registry. I am trying to decode some data which is in the `REG_BINARY` form and have no idea where to begin.
If you go to:

`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU\0`

You will find a series of values, 0, 1, 2, 3 e.t.c of type `REG_BINARY` and opening them sometimes shows what seems to be a folder along with a ton of what seems like gibberish.

I also need to understand the binary columns (`'Sort'` and `'Colinfo'`) of keys of the form:

`Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}`

I tried looking at shellbags python programs on the web but honestly have no idea what they are doing and they seem to be written with python2 in mind, so no dice.

I already wrote a small python program to help, but it is missing a way to get the node slot and I am trying to link any given folder name to a node slot. Here is my program currently.

```
from winreg import *
from codecs import decode

folder_reg_path = "Software\\Classes\\Local Settings\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\Shell\\Bags\\1375\\Shell"
bags_mru_path = "Software\\Classes\\Local Settings\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Shell\\BagMRU"

def get_sniffed_folder_type(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'SniffedFolderType')
        return '%s' % (value[0])


def get_current_nodeid(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key, 0, KEY_READ) as key:
        #value = QueryValueEx(key, '0')
        #return value[0].hex().decode('utf-8')
        value = EnumValue(key, 2)
        return decode(value[1], 'ascii', 'ignore')


# which clsid should be used? the last one in the list
def get_current_clsid(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        key_idx = 0
        value = None
        # keep looping until the last clsid entry is found
        while 1:
            try:
                temp = EnumKey(key, key_idx)
                key_idx += 1
                value = temp
            except:
                break
        return value


# the size of icons used by the folder
def get_folder_icon_size(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'IconSize')
        return '%d pixels' % (value[0])

# the folder view. details, list, tiles e.t.c
def get_logical_view_mode(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'LogicalViewMode')
        logical_view_mode_dict = {1 : "Details view", 2 : "Tiles view", 3 : "Icons view", 4 : "List view", 5 : "Content view"}
        return logical_view_mode_dict[value[0]]


# folder view is based on view mode. so you can have a  logical view mode of icons view with a view mode of large icons for instance
def get_folder_view_mode(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'Mode')
        # view_mode 7 is only available on xp. A dead os
        view_mode_dict = {1 : "Medium icons", 2 : "Small icons", 3 : "List", 4 : "Details", 5 : "Thumbnail icons", 6 : "Large icons", 8 : "Content"}
        return view_mode_dict[value[0]]


# how is the folder being sorted
def get_folder_sort_by(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'Sort')
        folder_sort_dict = {"0E000000" : "Date Modified", "10000000" : "Date Accessed", "0F000000" : "Date Created", "0B000000" : "Type", "0C000000" : "Size", "0A000000" : "Name", "02000000" : "Title", "05000000" : "Tags"}
        # we get a byte value which we will hexify and get a rather long string
        # similar to : 000000000000000000000000000000000100000030f125b7ef471a10a5f102608c9eebac0c000000ffffffff
        reg_value = value[0].hex()
        # now for this string, we need to get the last 16 strings. then we now get the first 8 out of it. so we will have
        folder_sort_dict_key = (reg_value[-16:][:8]).upper()
        #return folder_sort_dict[folder_sort_dict_key]
        print (reg_value)
        return folder_sort_dict_key

# in what order is the folder being sorted. ascending or descending???
def get_folder_sort_by_order(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'Sort')
        folder_sort_dict = {"01000000" : "Ascending", "FFFFFFFF" : "Descending"}
        # we get a byte value which we will hexify and get a rather long string
        # similar to : 000000000000000000000000000000000100000030f125b7ef471a10a5f102608c9eebac0c000000ffffffff
        reg_value = value[0].hex()
        # now for this string, we need to get the last 16 strings. then we now get the last 8 out of it. so we will have
        folder_sort_dict_key = (reg_value[-16:][-8:]).upper()
        return folder_sort_dict[folder_sort_dict_key]

# How is the folder being grouped
def get_folder_group_by(reg_key):
    with OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, reg_key) as key:
        value = QueryValueEx(key, 'GroupByKey:PID')
        folder_group_dict = {'10' : "Name", '14' : "Date Modified", '4*' : "Type", '12' : "Size", '15' : "Date Created", '5' : "Tags", '2' : "Title", '16' : "Date Accessed", '0' : "No Group Applied"}
        return folder_group_dict[str(value[0])]


# Registry is of the form:
# HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1375\Shell\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}
# where 1375 is a value called the NodeList, and {5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7} is a value under Shell chosen based on creation date

print ( 'The suggested folder type is %s' % get_sniffed_folder_type(folder_reg_path) )

# lets start by getting a value similar to {5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7} by finding the last child of folder_reg_path
folder_reg_path = folder_reg_path + '\\' + get_current_clsid(folder_reg_path)

print ( get_current_nodeid(bags_mru_path) )
print ( 'The registry path is %s' % (folder_reg_path) )
icon_size = get_folder_icon_size(folder_reg_path)
logical_view_mode = get_logical_view_mode(folder_reg_path)
view_mode = get_folder_view_mode(folder_reg_path)
sorted_by = get_folder_sort_by(folder_reg_path)
sorted_by_order = get_folder_sort_by_order(folder_reg_path)
folder_group_by = get_folder_group_by(folder_reg_path)
print ('The folder icon size is %s' % icon_size)
print('The folder logical view mode is %s' % logical_view_mode)
print('The folder view mode is %s' % view_mode)
print('The folder is sorted by %s in %s order' % (sorted_by, sorted_by_order))
print('The folder is grouped by: %s' % folder_group_by)
```

Comment: I've managed to decode BagMRU entries using PowerShell. Still looking for an answer???

Comment: Yes please. Abandoned this but would still like to know the solution. Thanks

Comment: Cool! There's a lot to cover to properly answer your two main questions: Decoding the binary values within a shellbag & decoding **BagMRU**, the index that associates a folder path with its corresponding shellbag. So I'll probably break it down into several parts --- there's a lot of out-dated/incomplete/half-right/just-plain-wrong info out there, so I want to do this right. Not sure if I should build one huge answer a piece at a time or seperate answers for each major topic --- I'll figure that out as I go along.

Comment: ok. looking forward to it. One long answer is probably better

Answer (score 11):

### Answer in progress. Please be patient...

When **Explorer** is opened for the first time in a newly-created account, The folder view will be dtermined by the *TopView* settings of the corresponding *FolderType* defined in the registry under:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes
```

Most users are familiar with a subset of these, the templates available on the **Customize** tab of a folder's **Properties** dialog:

- General Items (Generic)
- Documents
- Pictures
- Music
- Videos

**Contacts** and **Downloads** templates exist as well, but they are assigned only co their respective system folders using the paths found under:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

A complete list of *FolderType* IDs and their respective names can be generated with the following **PowerShell** code:

```
gp (gci HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes).PSPath |
   select PSChildName, CanonicalName | sort CanonicalName |
Out-GridView # or Out-File FTList.txt # or Set-Clipboard


PSChildName CanonicalName
----------- -------------
{db2a5d8f-06e6-4007-aba6-af877d526ea6} AccountPictures
{91475fe5-586b-4eba-8d75-d17434b8cdf6} Communications
{503a4e73-1734-441a-8eab-01b3f3861156} Communications.SearchResults
{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9} CompressedFolder
...
{5fa96407-7e77-483c-ac93-691d05850de8} Videos
{631958a6-ad0f-4035-a745-28ac066dc6ed} Videos.Library
{292108be-88ab-4f33-9a26-7748e62e37ad} Videos.LibraryFolder
{ea25fbd7-3bf7-409e-b97f-3352240903f4} Videos.SearchResults
```

Once a folder has been viewed in **Explorer**, **Windows** saves the view settings for that individual folder under two registry keys. If the folders are local, the keys are:

```
HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
```

--- and ---

```
HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

Network locations and a special bag, the Desktop layout, are here:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU
```

--- and ---

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags
```

The numbered subkeys under *Bags* each correspond to a folder. Each can save three seperate view states: ***Shell*** (Explorer), ***ComDLg*** (eg Notepad), and ***ComDlgLegacy*** (eg Reg Export). These can each have a GUID-named sub-key corresponding to the ID of the *FolderType* applied to the folder. That sub-key contains the various properties of the view:

```
PS C:\> $Bags = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
PS C:\> (gci $bags -Recurse | ? PSChildName -like "{*}" | select -first 2)[1] | ft -AutoSize

   Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local
   Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\1\Shell

Name                                   Property
----                                   --------
{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7} Rev              : 67
                                       FFlags           : 1090519041
                                       Vid              : {137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262}
                                       Mode             : 4
                                       LogicalViewMode  : 1
                                       IconSize         : 16
                                       Sort             : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
                                       ColInfo          : {0, 0, 0, 0...}
                                       GroupView        : 0
                                       GroupByKey:FMTID : {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
                                       GroupByKey:PID   : 0
                                       GroupByDirection : 1
```

```
Value Name       Description
----------       -----------
Rev              • Seems to be a counter that increments when BagMRU/Bags are deleted or Reset
                 Folders is executed from the Folder Options dialog
Fflags           • The FolderFlags that apply to the folder view.
GroupView        A DWORD flag determining whether or not the view is grouped:
                     • 0x00000000 = No grouping
                     • 0xffffffff = View grouped by column specified by the GroupByKey pair.
GroupByDirection A DWORD flag determing sort direction of group names:
                     • 0x00000001 = Ascending
                     • 0xffffffff = Descending
```

### Vid, Mode, LogicalViewMode, and IconSize are all detremined by the Icon mode:

```
Name        LVM Mode Vid                                    IconSize
----        --- ---- ---                                    --------
Details     1   4    {137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16
Tiles       2   8    {65F125E5-7BE1-4810-BA9D-D271C8432CE3} 48
SmIcons     3   1    {089000C0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16..31
Icons(M-XL) 3   1    {0057D0E0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 33..256
List        4   3    {0E1FA5E0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16
Content     5   8    {30C2C434-0889-4C8D-985D-A9F71830B0A9} 32
```

All of the values that specify columns:

- **ColInfo**
- **GroupBy**
- **Sort**

do so using by specifying the corresponding property as an ***FMTID- PID*** pair. The easiest way to determine the pair for a given property is to group a folder on that property, close it, and examine the resulting **GroupByKey:FMTID** and **GroupByKey:PID** values in the corresponding *Bag*. Here’s what I’ve got so far:

```
FMTID                                  PID    Name
-----                                  ---    ----
{14B81DA1-0135-4D31-96D9-6CBFC9671A99} 0x010f Camera Maker
{14B81DA1-0135-4D31-96D9-6CBFC9671A99} 0x0110 Camera Model
{14B81DA1-0135-4D31-96D9-6CBFC9671A99} 0x829a Exposure Time
{14B81DA1-0135-4D31-96D9-6CBFC9671A99} 0x8822 Expsure Program
{14B81DA1-0135-4D31-96D9-6CBFC9671A99} 0x9003 Date Taken
{14B81DA1-0135-4D31-96D9-6CBFC9671A99} 0x9204 Expsure Bias
{14B81DA1-0135-4D31-96D9-6CBFC9671A99} 0x9209 Flash Mode
{14B81DA1-0135-4D31-96D9-6CBFC9671A99} 0x920a Focal Length
{28636AA6-953D-11D2-B5D6-00C04FD918D0} 0x05   Computer
{56A3372E-CE9C-11D2-9F0E-006097C686F6} 0x02   Contributing Artists
{56A3372E-CE9C-11D2-9F0E-006097C686F6} 0x04   Album
{56A3372E-CE9C-11D2-9F0E-006097C686F6} 0x05   Year
{56A3372E-CE9C-11D2-9F0E-006097C686F6} 0x07   #
{56A3372E-CE9C-11D2-9F0E-006097C686F6} 0x0b   Genre
{56A3372E-CE9C-11D2-9F0E-006097C686F6} 0x0d   Album Artist
{56A3372E-CE9C-11D2-9F0E-006097C686F6} 0x23   Beats-per-minute
{56A3372E-CE9C-11D2-9F0E-006097C686F6} 0x24   Conductor
{5CBF2787-48CF-4208-B90E-EE5E5D420294} 0x15   Description
{5CBF2787-48CF-4208-B90E-EE5E5D420294} 0x17   DateVisited
{6444048F-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 0x0d   Dimensions
{64440491-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 0x03   Frame Width
{64440491-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 0x04   Frame Height
{64440491-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 0x06   Frame Rate
{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 0x04   Bit Rate
{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 0x0b   Copyright
{64440492-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 0x13   Composer
{9B174B34-40FF-11D2-A27E-00C04FC30871} 0x04   Owner
{A0E74609-B84D-4F49-B860-462BD9971F98} 0x64   35 mm Focal Length
{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC} 0x02   FolderName
{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC} 0x04   Type
{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC} 0x0a   Name
{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC} 0x0c   Size
{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC} 0x0d   Attributes
{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC} 0x0e   DateModified
{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC} 0x0f   DateCreated
{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC} 0x10   DateAccessed
{D35F743A-EB2E-47F2-A286-844132CB1427} 0x64   EXIF Version
{D5CDD502-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE} 0x02   Categories
{DABD30ED-0043-4789-A7F8-D013A4736622} 0x64   Folder
{E3E0584C-B788-4A5A-BB20-7F5A44C9ACDD} 0x06   FolderPath
{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9} 0x02   Title
{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9} 0x04   Authors
{F29F85E0-4FF9-1068-AB91-08002B27B3D9} 0x05   Tags
{F7DB74B4-4287-4103-AFBA-F1B13DCD75CF} 0x64   Date
```

In **ColInfo** & **Sort**, the pair is in a binary format, the [***PROPERTYKEY***](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb773381(v=vs.80)) structure:

```
typedef struct {
  GUID fmtid;
  DWORD pid;
} PROPERTYKEY;
```

There is some byte-shuffling in converting a CLSID-style GUID to its binary equivalent. Using **Name** as an example:

**`{B725F130-47EF-101A-A5F1-02608C9EEBAC} 0x0a`**

becomes

**`[30 f1 25 b7 ef 47 1a 10 a5 f1 02 60 8c 9e eb ac][0a 00 00 00]`**  ( Continuous in registry, grouped for clarity )

I use this **PowerShell** snippet to convert a binary GUID/CLSID to its more familiar text representaton:

```
$Bags = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
$Sample = gci $rp.Bags -Recurse | ? Property -Contains Sort | Select -First 5 | gp
$Sample | ForEach{ '{{{0}}}' -f [GUID][Byte[]]$_.Sort[20..35] }

Output:
{b725f130-47ef-101a-a5f1-02608c9eebac}
{b725f130-47ef-101a-a5f1-02608c9eebac}
{f29f85e0-4ff9-1068-ab91-08002b27b3d9}
{83914d1a-c270-48bf-b00d-1c4e451b0150}
{f7db74b4-4287-4103-afba-f1b13dcd75cf}
```

The **PROPERTYKEY** structures is used to build the structures that define **ColInfo** and **Sort**.  If we set a folder to have a single column, **Name**, and examine the resulting **ColInfo** value, we see the following bytes:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \ Constant
fd df df fd 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 / Header
[01 00 00 00] ← Column Count
[18 00 00 00] ← Byte count per column?
[[[30 f1 25 b7 ef 47 1a 10 a5 f1 02 60 8c 9e eb ac] ← FMTID
[0a 00 00 00] ← PID ] ← PROPERTYKEY
[da 01 00 00] ← Width (Pixels?) ] <- PROPERTYKEY/Width pair
```

For each column added to the view, the column count is incremented and the approprate PROPERTYKEY/Width pair is added:

```
[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
fd df df fd 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00]
[03 00 00 00]
[18 00 00 00]
[[[30 f1 25 b7 ef 47 1a 10 a5 f1 02 60 8c 9e eb ac]
[0d 00 00 00]] ← 'Attributes'
[53 00 00 00]]
[[[30 f1 25 b7 ef 47 1a 10 a5 f1 02 60 8c 9e eb ac]
[0a 00 00 00]] ← 'Name'
[10 01 00 00]]
[[[30 f1 25 b7 ef 47 1a 10 a5 f1 02 60 8c 9e eb ac]
[04 00 00 00]] ← 'Type'
[0a 01 00 00]]
```

**Sort** uses the [***SORTCOLUMN***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ns-shobjidl_core-sortcolumn) structure:

```
typedef struct SORTCOLUMN {
PROPERTYKEY propkey;
SORTDIRECTION direction; 
} SORTCOLUMN;
```

The **Sort** structure consists of:

- Header composed of 16 zero-valued bytes
- SORTCOLUMN count (DWORD)
- One or more SORTCOLUMN structures

**Name**, *ascending*:

```
[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00] <- Header
[01 00 00 00] <- SORTCOLUMN count
[[[30 f1 25 b7 ef 47 1a 10 a5 f1 02 60 8c 9e eb ac] <- FMTID
[0a 00 00 00] <- PID ] <- PROPERTYKEY
[01 00 00 00] <- Direction ] <- SORTCOLUMN
```

and **Name**, *descending*:

```
[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00]
[01 00 00 00]
[[[30 f1 25 b7 ef 47 1a 10 a5 f1 02 60 8c 9e eb ac]
[0a 00 00 00]]
[ff ff ff ff] <- Direction ] <- SORTCOLUMN
```

When secondary, tertiary or quaternary properties are selected via a **< Shift >+click** on the column header, the corresponding SORTCOLUMN is added to the **Sort** structure.

**Type**, *descending*, then **Name**, *ascending*:

```
(gp 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\66\Shell\{7D49D726-3C21-4F05-99AA-FDC2C9474656}\').Sort | Format-Hex                                               

           Path:

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000010   02 00 00 00 30 F1 25 B7 EF 47 1A 10 A5 F1 02 60  ....0ñ%·ïG..¥ñ.`
00000020   8C 9E EB AC 04 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF 30 F1 25 B7  ë¬........0ñ%·
00000030   EF 47 1A 10 A5 F1 02 60 8C 9E EB AC 0A 00 00 00  ïG..¥ñ.`ë¬....
00000040   01 00 00 00                                      ....

[00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00]
[02 00 00 00] <- Two columns specified
[[[30 f1 25 b7 ef 47 1a 10 a5 f1 02 60 8c 9e eb ac]
[04 00 00 00]] <- 'TYpe'
[ff ff ff ff]]
[[[30 f1 25 b7 ef 47 1a 10 a5 f1 02 60 8c 9e eb ac]
[0a 00 00 00]] <- 'Name'
[01 00 00 00]]
```

---

### **BagMRU**

**BagMRU** and its sub-keys are the tree-structured index that associates a folder's path with its numbered *Bag* (*NodeSlot*). **BagMRU** and its sub-keys mirror the [Shell Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro), with the **BagMRU** key itself corresponding to the rooted (virtual) *Desktop*. Each node in **BagMRU** corresponds to a folder in the Shell namespace. The fact that folders are referenced by their namespace path means one file system folder, say **Documents**, will have three separate views:

- Desktop\This PC\Documents
- Shell:UsersFilesFolder\Documents
- Desktop\This PC\C:\Users<*UserName*>\Documents

No folder names are readily apparent when examining **BagMRU**; the nodes have simple integer names, and there are no string values. Where's the human-readable path?!?!? Why does MS make everything so difficult?!?!?:D
Well,every integer-named node has a corresponding integer-named REG_BINARY value in its *parent* node. It is this value that identifies its associated sub-key. The key to the mystery? Those binary values are [***Item IDs***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro#item-ids) (actually the corresponding *ITEMID_CHILD* type of the [ITEMIDLIST structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shtypes/ns-shtypes-itemidlist)). So, we can use the ID Lists of a node and its ancestors to construct an *IDLIST_ABSOLUTE*, the analog to a fully-qualified path:
[image]

But it's still just an array of cryptic bytes. To extract meaningful information, we turn to the Windows API, specifically [***SHGetNameFromIDList***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shgetnamefromidlist). Per the documentation:

> "Retrieves the display name of an item identified by its IDList."

Fortunately, **PowerShell** can incorporate APIs via [***Add-Type***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7). Unfortunately, if PInvoke.net deosn't have a C# signature/wrapper in its database, discovering a working signature and wrapper can be frustrating. But through studying other signatures and trial-and-error, I hit on one and then defined a wrapper function:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition  @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

public class API
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)]
    static extern int SHGetNameFromIDList(IntPtr pidl, uint sigdnName, out StringBuilder ppszName);

    public static string GetFolderName(Byte[] IDL) {
        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(IDL, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr PIDL          = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        StringBuilder name   = new StringBuilder(2048);
        int result           = SHGetNameFromIDList(PIDL, 0x0, out name);
        pinnedArray.Free();
        return name.ToString();
    }
}
'@

# Invocation:
# $FolderName = [API]::GetFolderName($IDL)
# Where $IDL is a [Byte[]] ItemIDList
```

This is enough to deccode the IDLs of the folders rooted in the *Desktop*:

```
$BagMRU = 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU'
((Get-ItemProperty $Bagmru).PsObject.Properties).Where{$_.Name -match '\d+'} |
ForEach -Process{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'KeyName'  = $_.Name
        'Folder'   = [API]::GetFolderName($_.Value)
}}
```

OUtput: ( specific results will vary :D )

```
KeyName Folder
------- ------
0       Quick access
1       This PC
2       Keith Miller
3       Libraries
4       Control Panel
5       Sandbox
6       Search Results in Sandbox
7       Search Results in Sandbox
8       Search Results in Desktop
9       Search Results in Desktop
10      Keith Miller
11      ::{1434B6DB-0A53-454A-B1C7-69A56B454078}
12      Search Results in System32
13      Search Results in System32
14      Search Results in Keith Miller
15      Search Results in Altenate Folder Tree
16      Search Results in Altenate Folder Tree
17      H:\
18      I:\
19      Reg Transfers
20      Quick access
21      Quick access
22      This PC
23      Recent folders
24      OneDrive - Personal
25      This Device
26      Recent files
```

Nifty, huh? And don't worry, those "Search Results..." lines that appear to be duplicates aren't --- they work together. Because the `.SearchResults` and `.Library` *FolderTypes* have mutilple *TopViews* (selected via `ArrangeBy >`) available, one bag specifies which *TopView* is last used (and hence used when the folder is re-displayed) and the other one(s) hold the view settings for a specific `TopView`. More on that later --- we're not done with paths yet.

To construct the IDLs for the sub-folders, strip the two terminating null bytes from the "parent" byte array and then append the "child" byte array. If the child has sub0folders, repeat the process with the newly-constructed IDL.

With a fleshed-out `TypeDefinition` that includes an abbreviated enumeration of the ***SIGDN*** constants, a recursive function can be used to take a snapshot of the `BagMRU` keys and associate each node with it's corresponding path in the Shell namespace, as well as the filesytem path (where applicable) and the parsing path for virtual locations:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

[FlagsAttribute]
public enum SIGDN : uint {
    NORMALDISPLAY            = 0x00000000,
    DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING   = 0x80028000,
    FILESYSPATH              = 0x80058000,
    URL                      = 0x80068000,
};

public class API
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)]
    static extern int SHGetNameFromIDList(IntPtr pidl, SIGDN sigdnName, out StringBuilder ppszName);

    public static string Get_FolderName(Byte[] IDL , SIGDN sigdnName) {
        GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(IDL, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        IntPtr PIDL          = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        StringBuilder name   = new StringBuilder(2048);
        int result           = SHGetNameFromIDList(PIDL, sigdnName, out name);
        pinnedArray.Free();
        return name.ToString();
    }
}
'@

Function Get-BagMRU

#   Parametrs are for recursive calls only. Calling the function
#   with no parameters returns the complete collection.

{
    Param(
        [PSObject[]]$Keys  = ( Get-Item @(
            'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU',
            'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU'
        )),
        [Byte[]]$IDL          = [Byte[]]@(),
        [String]$ParentPath   = $null,
        [Byte[]]$ParentIDL    = [Byte[]]@()
    )
    ForEach ($key in $Keys)
    {
        If ( $IDL )
        {
            ### Build nameSpacePath ###

            [Byte[]]$absIDL = [Byte[]]($ParentIDL + $IDL)

            Try { $nameSpacePath = $ParentPath + [API]::Get_FolderName( $absIDL , 'NORMALDISPLAY' )
                } Catch { $nameSpacePath = $ParentPath + "{Disconnected}"
            }
            Try { $fileSysPath = [API]::Get_FolderName( $absIDL , 'FILESYSPATH' )
                } Catch { $fileSysPath = $null
            }
            Try { $parsingPath = [API]::Get_FolderName( $absIDL , 'DESKTOPABSOLUTEPARSING' )
                } Catch { $parsingPath = $null
            }
        }
        Else
        {
            $nameSpacePath = '\'
            $fileSysPath   = $null
            $parsingPath   = $null
        }

        ### Create custom object for current key ###
        $keyName             = $key.Name
        $node                = If ($keyName -match 'Local Settings') {'Local'} Else {'Network'} 
        If ( $bagNum  = $key.GetValue('NodeSlot') ) {} Else { $BagNum = 'n/a' }
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Node'           = $node
            'Bag'            = $bagNum
            'MruPath'        = ($keyName -split 'Shell\\')[-1]
            'NameSpacePath'  = $nameSpacePath
            'FileSysPath'    = $fileSysPath
            'ParsingPath'    = $parsingPath
            'IDL'            = $IDL
        }

        ### Recursively process subkeys ###
        
        If ($IDL)
        {
            $parentPath      = "$NameSpacePath\"
            $parentIDL       = $ParentIDL + $IDL[0..( $IDL.Length-3 )]
        }
        Else
        {
            $parentPath      = ''
            $parentIDL       = [Byte[]]@()
        }

        ForEach ( $subKeyName in $key.GetSubKeyNames() )
        {
            $Splat = @{
                'Keys'       = $key.OpenSubKey( $subKeyName ) 
                'IDL'        = $key.GetValue( $subKeyName )
                'ParentPath' = $parentPath
                'ParentIDL'  = $parentIDL
            }
            Get-BagMRU @Splat
        }
    }
}

( $MRUSnapshot = Get-BagMRU ) | Out-GridView
```

### To be continued...

Comment: Does anybody know how I turn off the colorization in the code blocks, or specify **PowerShell** as the language?

Comment: Ok this took me a while to digest. Thanks

Comment: I'm going to continue wiht an examples digging deeper into BagMRU. Just have other things going on & want to double-check old code.

Comment: thamks. wonder why they had such a complicated system in the first place