# Setting visible columns on new directory

Tags: c++, winapi, directory, com, multiple-columns

I'm developing a shell extension that creates a new folder. I'd like the new folder to display a set of custom columns in details view once the user browses into it. I thought that maybe `IColumnManager` was the correct interface to accomplish this. This is the code I'm trying after the new folder has been created (I've abbreviated the PKEYs):

```
IShellFolder* psdf;
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetDesktopFolder(&psdf))) {

    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl = ILCreateFromPath(pwszNewFolderPath);

    LPSHELLFOLDER psf;
    if (SUCCEEDED(psdf->BindToObject(pidl, NULL, IID_IShellFolder, (void**)& psf))) {

        SFV_CREATE sfvc = { 0 };
        sfvc.cbSize = sizeof(SFV_CREATE);
        sfvc.pshf = psf;
        sfvc.psvOuter = NULL;
        sfvc.psfvcb = NULL;

        LPSHELLVIEW psv;
        if (SUCCEEDED(SHCreateShellFolderView(&sfvc, &psv))) {

            IColumnManager* pcm;
            if (SUCCEEDED(psv->QueryInterface(IID_IColumnManager, (void**)& pcm))) {

                PROPERTYKEY rgkeys[] = {
                    PKEY_ [...] ,
                    PKEY_ [...] ,
                    PKEY_ [...] ,
                };

                if (SUCCEEDED(pcm->SetColumns(rgkeys, ARRAYSIZE(rgkeys)))) {
                    //MessageBoxA(NULL, "Success?", "Success?", MB_OK);
                }
                pcm->Release();
            }
            psv->Release();
        }
        psf->Release();
    }
    psdf->Release();
}
```

This code successfully executes each method call, but when I go into the newly created folder, the columns aren't as desired. Am I doing something wrong? Does `IColumnManager` work only when a given folder is already visible? Maybe it's only for `IExplorerBrowser` or something? And if it's not the right interface, how can I set a set of custom columns for when the user browses into a folder?  Thanks.

EDIT: This code actually works on an active view of the folder. However, the changes it makes to the columns do not persist (unlike column changes made manually by the user, which do persist).  So I guess I'm wondering if there's a way to make them persist, or if there's another approach to set columns without requiring an active view.  Thanks again.

Also, might `SHGetViewStatePropertyBag` be relevant? Along with `IExplorerBrowser::SetPropertyBag`?  Or could those not be used for regular shell folders?

Comment: Note that `IColumnManager::SetColumns` clears the state of all columns, so `IColumnManager::SetColumnInfo` must be called afterward to set the state of individual columns.

Comment: Thanks, I think `SetColumnInfo` works, as long as the folder view is active.  So that's good.  Do you happen to know if you can set the columns when the folder is not being viewed?  Thanks again!

Comment: The set of columns (and their state, SHCOLSTATE) is decided by the IShellFolder interface implementation. Do you own the folder? aka: do you write a Shell Namespace Extension?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  It's just a directory I create and that I make into a system folder.

Comment: Binding to a normal "DOS" path gives you the basic system implementation of IShellFolder and it supports all columns that apply to file-system items.

Comment: @Anders I'm not sure I understand.  Could you explain?  Are you saying it's possible to set columns without the folder in view?

Comment: I was just saying that `ILCreateFromPath`+`SHGetDesktopFolder->BindToObject` gives you Microsoft's IShellFolder implementation. Use `IExplorerBrowser` like I say in my answer to navigate to the folder and then query for the active shell view with `IExplorerBrowser::GetCurrentView`. Calling SetPropertyBag is probably a good idea as well.

Comment: So does that mean I have to create my own window to host an IExplorerBrowser, or I'm just getting File Explorer's?  Sorry, I'm still learning how this shell stuff works.

Comment: You need your own window to host IExplorerBrowser but it might not even need to be a visible window. See https://www.codeproject.com/articles/17809/host-windows-explorer-in-your-applications-using-t# and https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=11133 for hosting tips. IExplorerBrowser implements IShellBrowser and most of the undocumented details for you. IExplorerBrowser is not exactly the same thing as a Explorer window but pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

`SHCreateShellFolderView` creates a instance of the shell provided `IShellView` and this interface knows how to save its settings but it asks its `IShellBrowser` host for the storage implementation. `IShellView::CreateViewWindow` connects the view to its host.

`IShellView::SaveViewState`:

> Saves the Shell's view settings so the current state can be restored during a subsequent browsing session.

But you need to implement `IShellBrowser` and call something like `SHGetViewStatePropertyBag` to get the storage implementation used by Explorer and give this to `IShellView` when it asks for it. Most of the details here are undocumented and I would recommend that you use `IExplorerBrowser` to navigate to the folder instead of trying to host `IShellView` on your own. Use "Shell" as the bag name.

`SHGetViewStatePropertyBag` was added in Windows XP but `IExplorerBrowser` does not exist there. If you need to support < Vista you must debug Explorer to discover [the undocumented interface](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fcb4a319-246a-47dd-9fb5-730d754d2fbc/ishellview-viewstate-persistence?forum=windowsuidevelopment) that is the glue between `IShellView` and `SHGetViewStatePropertyBag`.

On Windows 2000 and older I believe the state is stored directly in the `IStream` and not in a property bag. `OpenRegStream` is used to open the stream but the function that calculates the MRU path is undocumented but [KB 812003](https://web.archive.org/web/20041020061510/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813711) at least tells you the root.

Comment: BFO_BROWSER_PERSIST_SETTINGS might change where settings are stored, but again, undocumented.

Comment: I know this thread is a little old, but I've been playing with **Explorer** views for years ( since XP ) -- initially with VBScript and now with **PowerShell**. I finally figured out how to decode `BagMRU` and its subkeys ( `NirSoft's ` **`ShellBagsView`** `is inaccurte/incomplete` ) and associate them with their corresponding location in the Shell namespace. Following this thread now, so if anyone's interested, reply to tthis coment.

Comment: @KeithMiller Of course, we are always interested in undocumented shell details.

Comment: See my reply here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56451366/need-help-decoding-registry-binary-data/61240563#61240563   Basically, the binary values in the numerically-named values of BagMRU are the bytes that form the IDL of the numreically corresponding subkey. You can chain them together, dropping the two terminating null bytes of all but the final value, and you've got a fully-qualified IDL. Of course normally, just the pointers, PIDLs, are passed in code. But I imagine this structure optimizes lookup of property bags.